# Cannot connect to local instance of Amazon Redshift running on Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-redshift

Bear with me guys I am a novice with both Amazon Redshift and Docker.
I have tried to run a local instance of Amazon Redshift using the following docker image guildeducation/docker-amazon-redshift

The command I used is the follwing:

docker run -d -p 5439:5439 -v $(pwd):/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my-password --name my-redshift guildeducation/docker-amazon-redshift

By inspecting the active image using the command "docker inspect my-redshift", everything seems to be fine.

My problem is connecting with the database instance. I don't even known if one was created by the docker command I run earlier.

To connect to the local instance I am using SQL Workbench/J as suggested by Amazon documentation.
[image]

Clearly I am missing something.

Probably I didn't create a database instance. In this case, how do I create an instance on docker?

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: Is the name of your machine `endpoint`?

Comment: I added the IP address of the the docker image using the command "docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' my-redshift". I replaced endpoint with the ip address, but the connection times out

Comment: jdbc:redshift://my_IP:5439/

Comment: Amazon Redshift is a cloud data warehouse _service_. You cannot possibly be running it locally. [Source: I work at AWS on the Redshift team.]

Comment: Thanks Joe for your feedback. I thought to start to work locally and  I found this docker image guildeducation/docker-amazon-redshift. I was naive.